# How can I filter the result of label_values(label) to get a list of labels that match a regex?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I have several metrics with the label "service". I want to get a list of all the "service" levels that begin with "abc" and end with "xyz". These will be the values of a grafana template variable.

This is that I have tried:
`label_values(service) =~ "abc.*xyz"`

However this produces a error `Template variables could not be initialized: parse error at char 13: could not parse remaining input "(service_name) "...`

Any ideas on how to filter the label values?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This should work (replacing `up` with the metric you mention):

```
label_values(up{service=~"abc.*xyz"}, service)
```

Or, in case you actually need to look across multiple metrics (assuming that for some reason some metrics have some service label values and other metrics have other values):

```
label_values({__name__=~"metric1|metric2|metric3", service=~"abc.*xyz"}, service)
```

Comment: What if the filter you want is a grafana graph variable - where the abc.* was a filter in a grafana dropdown.   Is the variable usable in the PromQL as $grafana_Var or ${{grafana_Var}}....

Comment: According to Grafana documentation (https://grafana.com/docs/reference/templating/) both`$grafana_Var` and `[[grafana_Var]]` should work. Although (on an unrelated note) that name looks very unusual. I've seen `snake_case` names and `camelCase` names, but never `snake_Camel_Case` names. (o: